# In Hybris, how can I get an attribute from a Product Model in Java?

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to get the an attribute as shown in HmC under Website > Products > Administration (Tab) > Unbound (Group) > Divison (Field).

Is it possible to extract the value from Java with the ProductModel Class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the easiest way to get the value of this field is by exploring its qualifier using HMC so :

```
1- Hmc -> System -> Types -> Search for product
```

[image]

2- after that go Properties tab, you will find all attributes and look for the name of this field , in your case : **divison**, see the following pic

[image]

Comment: This has been very helpful! Though I used a different approach by editing the **project name here**-beans.xml file in resources which is the same and adding the field I wanted visible in the Model. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The administration tab should also contain the ***"Type"*** attribute, in the ***"Metadata"*** group.
Let's say the type is "*SubscriptionProduct*".For this type you should find the associated
java class, which in our example is *SubscriptionProduct**Model***.This java class(or any parent class)
 should contain all the attributes that are visible in the HMC(in all tabs) for that particular instance.

If the type is indeed "Product", yes, you should be able to get the attribute from the ProductModel class.If it is a type which inherits Product, then the attribute might be defined just for that particular subclass and will not be available in Product Model class

Also take note that the HMC displays the locale associated with a field.
 For example the product's "Sales unit" attribute (from the properties tab)
 has a locale defined for it in  core-locales_en.properties :
 type.product.unit.name=Sales unit

So I guess you should search in all the files which have the .properties extension
 after "Divison" to find the locale file in which was defined, and to actually see the atribute as it is defined in 
 the {extensionName}-items.xml

Comment: Thanks! What I did is I edited {extensionName}-beans.xml then did ant build, started the server to open admin and updated the core. The attribute (eg. Division) should be visible as ProductModel.setDivision or getDivision.

Comment: I think {extensionName}-beans.xml should be used only for DTO objects
Ex: **de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.product.data.ProductData** is a class that is being generated(during build) from the **commercefacades-beans.xml** file.The attributes that are visible in HMC are defined in {extensionName}-items.xml